# PostgreSQL rounding error | Sum of differences between values and difference between sum of values are not equal

Tags: postgresql, floating-point

I am trying to evaluate numbers upto 3 decimal precision. The formulas are fairly simple but sum of differences between values and difference between sum of values are not equal.

The dataset contains nearly 2050 entries.

```
result_column_1 = SUM(column1) - SUM(column2)
result_column_2 = SUM(column1-column2)
```

I am getting a huge dissimilarity between result_column_1 and result_column_2

column1 and column2 are already truncated (not rounded) to 3 decimal places.

```
1. ROUND() - didn't work
2. CAST TO Demical, Numeric - didn't work
3. TRUNC() - didn't work
```

Comment: Please, add your table description and maybe some entries :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: For fewer entries, it did result in the same answer!!

Comment: @KenWhite, I believe that's exactly the issue but couldn't find appropriate answers.

Comment: That **is** the appropriate answer. Floating point math isn't always exact, and especially when summing many values, the minor differences add up, causing larger errors.

Comment: That **is** the appropriate answer. Floating point math isn't always exact, and especially when summing many values, the minor differences add up, causing larger errors.

Comment: @KenWhite, is there any way that I can avoid or reduce it? The values being used in further multiplication calculations result in a colossal mismatch.